# Do I need to install a database program on another PC when deploying a JavaFX app?

Tags: javafx, derby, javadb

Hi I want to install my JavaFX app on another PC.

I'm using JavaDB and I get a database error on the other pc. On my pc everything works fine.

Now my question is, do I need to completely setup a database program just to install the app?

And in case of yes, what do I need to install for JavaDB? I could not properly find this.

This is the error:

> error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message
>   connection refused: connect

Comment: You should know how to install the database as it seems to be present on your pc? And for your question subject: Depends. Some databases are in-memory / just a jar (sqlite, h2) which you normally deploy with your app. Other dbms (mysql, postresql, etc) rely on an external server. EDIT: Didn't see the derby tag, sorry. It should be sufficient to deploy the derby.jar along all other dependencies with your application

Comment: I have the derby jar in my dependencies folder, but it still doesnt work

Comment: After your question update: You try to access a derby server via network connection. With this setup you have to manually install derby at the client machine in server mode. Do you need the same database for all clients? Or has every client it's own database? In the latter case you can find further information on using files (not network) for accessing a derby database [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop14.html)